# Product of two independent Student distributions

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, t-distribution

What is the product of two independent student t distributions?
In which case does this product product result in another t distribution?

Comment: Because exact formulas are messy and there is no product that results in a t distribution, would you mind explaining the statistical motivation for this question?  We might be able to suggest alternative approaches or more useful related questions.

Comment: Explaining why I need this product would be a little bit complicated, but I am looking for a special case when the product of 2 t distribution will give a t distribution or an unnormalized t distribution

Comment: Could you clarify what an "unnormalized" t distribution might be?

Comment: I reformulated my problem so it will result in answering the following question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576853/integration-of-the-sum-of-gaussians-over-a-line

Comment: The distribution corresponding to the product of several $t$ densities is called a [poly-t distribution.](https://www.proquest.com/openview/e78e6bdd70a98d3db7e8444a328a61d9/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y,$ the density of their product can be found with a change of variables as

$$f_{XY}(z) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_X(x) f_Y(z/x)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}.$$

Ignoring normalizing constants (we'll consider these at the end), for two Student t densities with $\nu$ and $\mu$ degrees of freedom this integrand is proportional to

$$h(x,z) = \left(1 + \frac{x^2}{\mu}\right)^{-(\mu+1)/2}\,  \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{x^2\nu}\right)^{-(\nu+1)/2}\,\frac{1}{|x|}.$$

**Let's find a lower bound for $f(z)$ when $z$ is small.**  To do so, we may restrict the region of integration and we may replace the integrand by anything that never exceeds it.

Let $z$ be positive but less than $1$ and consider the integration region where $x^2\nu$ ranges between $z^2$ and $1.$  To get an appreciation for what's going on, here (with $\mu=\nu=1$) are plots of $h(x,z)$ for $|z| = 1$ (blue), $1/2, 1/4,$ and $1/8$ (red).

[image: Figure]

You can see that as $|z|$ approaches $0,$ there's more and more area pushed into this region.  That's no surprise: we would expect the largest area (which corresponds to the highest density of the product) to be at the center of the product distribution, which (by symmetry) must be $0.$  But how large does it get?

Over the region $x^2/\nu \in[z^2, 1]$ the first factor of $h$ is smallest when $x$ is smallest and the second factor is smallest when $x$ is largest, whence throughout this region

$$\begin{aligned}
h(x,z) &\ge \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{\mu\nu}\right)^{-(\mu+1)/2}\,  \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{1}\right)^{-(\nu+1)/2}\,\frac{1}{|x|} \\
&\ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{\mu\nu}\right)^{-(\mu+1)/2}\,  \left(1 + 1\right)^{-(\nu+1)/2}\,\frac{1}{|x|}.
\end{aligned}$$

The second inequality is a consequence of $z^2 \le 1.$

The factors before $1/|x|$ are constant (but nonzero), depending only on $\mu$ and $\nu,$ so again let's consider them later and ignore them now. As $x$ varies over just the positive part of this region it runs from $z/\sqrt{\nu}$ to $1/\sqrt{\nu},$ giving a lower bound proportional to

$$\int_{z/\sqrt{\nu}}^{1/\sqrt{\nu}} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|} = -\log z.$$

**As $z\to 0,$ this lower bound diverges.**  Consequently, *no matter what the constants of proportionality are that we ignored,* $f_{XY}(z)$ diverges at $0.$

Here, to illustrate, is a histogram from a simulation of ten million products (with $\nu=\mu=1/2$).  Almost a million of those products are represented.  The red curve is the negative logarithm.  Clearly it approximates the density well near zero.

[image: Figure]

However, any Student t distribution with (say) $\kappa \gt 0$ degrees of freedom has a value proportional to $(1 + 0^2/\kappa)^{-(\kappa+1)/2} = 1$ at the origin, which is *finite.*  Consequently, **the product of two independent Student t distributions is never (even remotely like) a Student t distribution.**

---

The product density can be found analytically as a polynomial combination of Riemann hypergeometric functions.  Since this product is never a Student t distribution, though, I did not see any point into providing further details.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed analysis. this makes sense now. For the special case when the degree of freedom is 1 therefore the t distribution is a cauchy distribution, it is possible to find the result of the product of  two t(1)?

Comment: @sam It seems so, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451744

Comment: Yes, that result is correct.  But generally, for arbitrary degrees of freedom, the PDF of the product does not attain such a simple form: various versions of hypergeometric functions show up, such as elliptic functions.