# Integration of the sum of gaussians over a line

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

suppose we have two independent gaussian distributions $X$ and $Y$ .
let $Z = X+Y$ which will be a gaussian too.
the goal is to compute :

$ \int_{L} P(X+Y=c) dXdY$

Where L is the line : $X+Y=c$.
$P(X+Y=c)$ is the probability that a point is on the line L.
My professor told me that this integral is equal to $G_z(c)$. Where $G_z$ is the density function of $Z$.

I need to know where this result come from and how to prove it.

This integral comes in the following scope:

Let's suppose that we want to find the probability that a point 'k' will be on the line  L= X+Y=c.
To do so we need to compute the following: 
$ p(k|X+Y=c) = \frac {p_x(X_k)p_y(Y_k)}{p(X+Y=c)} = \frac {p_x(X_k)p_y(Y_k)}{\int_{L} p_x(X)p_y(Y) dX dY}$

where k is point over the line L.
For this to happen we will use a base for the line L define as a vector b(b1,b2) and a point of origin r(r1,r2). Therefore, the previous integral can be written as: 
$ \frac {p_x(X_k)p_y(Y_k)}{\int_{t} p_x(r_1+b_1t)p_y(r_2+b_2t) dt}  = \frac {p_x(r_1+b_1k)p_y(r_2+b_2k)}{\int_{t} p_x(r_1+b_1t)p_y(r_2+b_2t) dt}$

The theorem that my professor stated is to compute the value of the integral of the denominator which should be equal to Z(0) in this case. But I need a proof for that theorem.

Comment: This notation makes no sense.  Please write your integral using standard notation or else define your notation.

Comment: could you tell me what is not clear about it so I can fix it?

Comment: Nothing about it is clear.  Any well-defined integral will clearly exhibit (1) an interval of integration and (2) a measure or function that is being integrated.  Your "$X$" and "$Y$" are none of the above--either they are "distributions," or they are random variables, or they are variables in the plane used to define a line implicitly.  If we try to understand your integral as literally described, then it must be zero, because the line has measure zero with respect to the distribution of $(X,Y).$ Moreover, on the line $X+Y=c,$ necessarily $Z=c,$ so there's nothing (variable) to integrate.

Comment: yeah you are right. I edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you wrote that integral out exactly as the professor had it?  Otherwise, as @whuber observes, on the line $X+Y=c$, $Z=c$, so there's no probability density left to integrate over; $Z=c$ by construction, and the probability that it does so equals $1$.

Comment: I had a mistake there but I fix it. It should be like that

Comment: Re "let's suppose:" except for degenerate variables $X$ and $Y$ (which are constants), the chance that $(X,Y)$ lies on any particular line is *zero.*  It is truly impossible to determine for sure what problem you are trying to solve.